# Do the rmiregistry or JNDI store the object in serialized form

Tags: java, jndi, rmi

I read that I can use the rmiregistry or JNDI as a directory service for RMI. As far as I understood, the stub for remote objects is stored and associated with a key in such a directory service.

Now my question is, is the stub stored in serialized form or as an "active" object in the rmiregistry/JNDI?

If it stored serialized wouldn't the distributed garbage collection fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that I can use the rmiregistry or JNDI as a directory service for RMI.

No you didn't. You read that you can use the Registry as a directory service, and JNDI as an API for it.

> As far as I understood, the stub for remote objects is stored and associated with a key in such a directory service.

Correct.

> Now my question is, is the stub stored in serialized form or as an "active" object in the rmiregistry/JNDI?

It is serialized to the Registry and deserialized on arrival (unmarshalling). Inside the Registry it is a normal Java object.

> if it is stored serialized ...

It isn't.

JNDI really has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why RMI registry stores remote objects as "active" objects is that the RMI registry is just a regular RMI object. It exposes its operations via the `java.rmi.registry.Registry` interface, which is a regular `java.rmi.Remote` interface.

There is actually one small difference from regular RMI objects - RMI registry [gets exported](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-16-ga/src/java.rmi/share/classes/sun/rmi/registry/RegistryImpl.java#L220) as a permanent object - it is an internal option that makes an object not subject to distributed garbage collection.